# webpage expired IE8

Tags: php, javascript, browser, internet-explorer-8

some of our clients are experiencing a "Web Page Expired" error in IE8 on our site. I've tried it myself in IE8 but am having no problems, and have heard it might be something to do with having "Do not save encrypted pages to disk" checked under Internet options. I enabled this on my browser and still could not replicate the problem.

The page in question has a form that gets auto submitted by javascript and then processed with PHP. It then redirects to another page after processing. Could something here be the root of the problem?

Thanks!

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function doSubmit()
{
this.document.autoForm.submit();
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="window.setTimeout('doSubmit()', 1000)">
<form name="autoForm" method="POST" action="process.php">
<input type="hidden" name="handlerID" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Side note: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval` (which is `evil`)!   Pass functions: `setTimeout(doSubmit, 1000)`.

Answer (score 1):

The "Web Page Expired" message usually occurs when you are trying to go back (via the browser's "Back" button) to a page to which you just `POST`ed data.

Basically, imagine if you were trying to create a new user. Your New User form takes the UserName, Password, and `POST`s it to the **Create a User** page. This page then sends you to the **Welcome to the Site** page.

If you were to hit back, your browser would try to send you back to the **Create a User** page. But your browser recognizes that you just `POST`ed data here.

"Web Page Expired" is IE's way of asking a user if they would like to re-submit their form (and create a second user), or if they would rather reload the page without any `POST` variables.

---

### How do you fix this?

If the data that you are sending is small (it looks like it is just a number in this case), then a possible workaround would be to pass this value to `process.php` with `GET` rather than `POST`. `GET` requests traditionally do not create or delete anything, so your browser is ok with sending you there a second time.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly as no one is hitting the back button? It's just happening automatically, and the form that is being submitted by the JS, is being submitted to a completely different page 'process.php'.

Comment: Can you describe the workflow a bit more? As I understand it, someone comes to `Page1.php`. The page automatically submits a form (via JavaScript) to `process.php`. Finally, `process.php` sends them to `Page3.php`. Is this right?

Comment: Also, is there a way to figure out which page is showing the "Web Page Expired" message? Do you have access to anything that records which pages users visit?

Comment: The person starts on Page1.php, this posts information to the page with the code above which we'll call Page2.php. This has a form which autosubmits to Process.php. Process.php handles the request, and redirects the user to a Page4.php.

I don't have any access to the system for the user experiencing the problem, but it's a work computer using IE8, and all other work machines at that workplace are experiencing the same thing.

I asked them to send me a screengrab and from that I can see that it is getting stuck on page2.php, which is the page with the auto-submitted form above.

Comment: I've heard of issues similar to this (where an entire office of people is having a bizarre web problem) before: the problem is usually related to a proxy server caching all of the pages. Everyone at the office might be accessing the web through a server at the office. If the server is caching things inappropriately, then it might cause the affects that you are describing. After that, I'm out of ideas :(